# Was Olivia really called "Han", or was that a false memory?

Tags: fringe

> OLIVIA: Well, I guess that I've always just enjoyed being on my own. Even when I was at boarding school, they used to call me "Han".
>   PETER: As in "Solo"? That's cute. At least you had a nickname.

In episode S1E10 of *Fringe*, Olivia mentions to Peter that she likes to be alone. She even used to have a nickname: "Han"  (Solo).

Later in the episode, we learn that Olivia has some false memories that she thinks are her own.

> They are not hers, but John Scott's.

What about this particular memory? *Was she really called "Han" at boarding school?*

Comment: I believe that this is the only reference to her going to boarding school, but there's even less background on John Scott so we don't know if he went to boarding school either.

Comment: There's not enough information to say. On the one hand, it would fit with what we know of Olivia. On the other hand, it does seem a bit odd that the boarding school kids would call a female Olivia by a male character's name

Answer (score 1):

I guess that, just like Alan and Jason Baker said, there is no formal answer. But, if we look at her background, childhood and her personality, and read between the lines, I believe that this particular memory, being called "Han" at the boarding school, is hers and not Agent Scott's memory.

As a child, due to the Cortexiphan trials and to the incident with her stepfather (when she was 9 years old), she was the type that prefers staying alone rather than mixing up with others and socializing (you will notice also that this trait differentiates her from the Fauxlivia). She has built barriers around herself for protection.
You can take a look at the following links and it will help you paint a general portrait of Olivia (from being young to adult).

So to resume, personally, I believe strongly that it was her memory (being called "Han") and this belief seems to be shared amongst Fringe's fans.

---

Link 1 - http://www.fringetelevision.com/2012/09/fringe-analysisreview-501-hope-can-be.html
Link 2 - http://www.themarysue.com/let-us-discuss-how-great-fringes-olivia-dunham-is/